# What is escape property in query_string in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-7

I have a problem using wildcard in query_string in elasticsearch.I can not find documentation for the "escape" property in query_string when the value is "true" I got some results but when it is "false" the result is zero.

```
{
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*Serial\\+*",
                        "fields": [
                            "info.name^1.0"
                        ],
                        "type": "best_fields",
                        "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
                        "analyze_wildcard": true,
                        "escape": true,
                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
                        "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                }
```

can anybody explain the "escape" property?

Comment: Rule of thumb. If it's not documented, you should not use it.

Comment: I opened an issue on github to add this flag to the docs, https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/77604

Answer (score 3):

Weird that its not documented, but looking at the source code we can see:

[Es query string source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/bb9c91fc5729d1fa474e249318634971c57d3f74/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryStringQueryBuilder.java#L824)

If "escape" is "true", the code calls
[org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.escape](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape-java.lang.String-)

On the query string, the function itself is documented as

> Returns a String where those characters that QueryParser expects to be escaped are escaped by a preceding \.

So looks like this flag is just used to automatically escape characters for you, so you don't have to manually escape them

Comment: So this query (```"query": "*Serial\\+*" , "escape": false```) must has  same result as (```"query": "*Serial+*" , "escape": true```) but their results aren't same. The first one returns zero doc and the second returns 30 docs.

Comment: @sabasafavi in the first one you don't escape `*`. Isn't that the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code of `QueryStringQueryBuilder.java` ([Github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/63012c8a40742829806b44cb6577b05d9ab25a83/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/QueryStringQueryBuilder.java#L824)), we find

```java
public class QueryStringQueryBuilder extends AbstractQueryBuilder<QueryStringQueryBuilder> {

    // ...

    public static final boolean DEFAULT_ESCAPE = false;

    // ...

    private boolean escape = DEFAULT_ESCAPE;

    // ...

    public QueryStringQueryBuilder(StreamInput in) throws IOException {
        // ...
        escape = in.readBoolean();
        // ...
    }

    // ...

    protected Query doToQuery(SearchExecutionContext context) throws IOException {
        String rewrittenQueryString = escape ? org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.escape(this.queryString) : queryString;
        // ...
    }
}
```

So it governs whether the query string is passed through the Lucene [classic QueryParser's `.escape()` method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape-java.lang.String-), or not.

This parameter appears to be relevant if you want to use Lucene's query language instead of KQL. It might be a helper parameter for Kibana's web-based query interface, where you can switch between the two dialects.

Overall - if it's not documented, it's probably not meant for public use.